# Loading PIG output files into Hive table with some blank cells

Tags: azure, hive, apache-pig, sandbox, etl

I have successfully loaded a 250000 record CSV file into HDFS and I have performed some ETL functions on it such as removing any characters in a string other than 0-9, a-z and A-Z so that it's nice and clean.

I've saved the output of this ETL to the HDFS for loading into Hive. While in Hive I created the schema for the table and set the appropriate data types for each column.

```
create external table pigOutputHive (
  id string,
  Score int,
  ViewCount int,
  OwnerUserId string,
  Body string,
  Rank int
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
location '/user/admin/PigOutputETL';
```

When I run a simple query on the data such as:

```
SELECT * FROM pigoutputhive LIMIT 100000;
```

The data looks as it should, and when i download it to my local machine and view it in Excel as a CSV it also looks good.

When I try and run the following query on the same table I get every field being returned as an integer even for the string columns. See the screenshot below.

[image: Hive Output with Integers for all columns]

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? Of the original 250000 rows there are some blanks in a particular fields such as the OwnerUserId, do I need to tell Pig or Hive how to handle these?

Comment: Are these on HDInsight?

Comment: @juvchan I don't believe so, I am running Hortonworks Sandbox on a VM on the Azure cloud. I think HDInsight is something different.

Comment: I've also tried the original file without the blanks and I am still getting the same results!!

Comment: @WolfPig why do you think it return as integer ? you can run on a test record where you have "test string" in the string columns ?